# Hive - collect_list with multiple columns?

Tags: sql, hive

Say my table looks like this:

```
Name,Subject,Score
Jon,English,80
Amy,Geography,70
Matt,English,90
Jon,Math,100
Jon,History,60
Amy,French,90
```

Is there a way to use `collect_list` so that I can get my query as such:

```
Jon: English:80; Math:100; History:60
Amy: Geography:70; French:90
Matt: English:90
```

EDIT:

The complication here is that the `collect_list` UDF permits only one argument, i.e. one column. 
Something like

```
SELECT name, collect_list(subject), collect_list(score) from mytable group by name
```

results in

```
Jon          |    [English,Math,History]       |     [80,100,60]
Amy          |    [Geography,French]           |     [70,90]
Matt         |    [English]                    |     [90]
```

Comment: based on what you need as output you would need a `map` instead of a `list` i guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you needed.

```
select * from t0;

+-------+------------+-------+--+
| t0.a  |    t0.b    | t0.c  |
+-------+------------+-------+--+
| Jon   | English    | 80    |
| Amy   | Geography  | 70    |
| Matt  | English    | 90    |
| Jon   | Math       | 100   |
| Jon   | History    | 60    |
| Amy   | French     | 90    |
+-------+------------+-------+--+

select a, collect_list(concat_ws(':',b,cast(c as string))) from t0 group by a;

+-------+-----------------------------------------+--+
|   a   |                   _c1                   |
+-------+-----------------------------------------+--+
| Amy   | ["Geography:70","French:90"]            |
| Jon   | ["English:80","Math:100","History:60"]  |
| Matt  | ["English:90"]                          |
+-------+-----------------------------------------+--+
```